# I can run and get output for my code in Eclipse, but unable to run through the command prompt

Tags: java

Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Notes has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

```
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

I have set my path with the latest version of jdk as well as jre.
jdk1.8.0_111
jre1.8.0_192

I can compile the code by using javac Notes.java

but unable to get the output for that helloworld program,

```
  public class Notes{
  public static void main(String []args){
  System.out.println("hello world");
   }

   }
```

Comment: Why do you have different version of Jdk and Jre ?

Comment: It looks like your JRE is to old

Comment: can u pls suggest me which version of jre I need to install??